# IB Outlet for NativeAd is nil in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xib

```
  let nativeAdCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
      withIdentifier: "Ads", for: indexPath) as! NativeAds
```

then

```
 (nativeAdCell.HeadlineView).text = nativeAd.headline
        (nativeAdCell.PriceView).text = nativeAd.price
```

When running, an error occurs stating Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. which means the view is nil

edit 1

```
   tableview.register(NativeAds.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Ads")


   let nativeAdCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
       withIdentifier: "Ads", for: indexPath) as! NativeAds
```

Is how I registered it, I'm using an Xib file for this

Comment: How did you register your cell class?  Are you using a storyboard? Have you set the outlet? Did the tableview come from that storyboard? Why are you force downcasting the property to a `UILabel`?  The property should already have the right type. If it has a different type then force downcasting can also result in a crash.

Comment: edited it and thnx for the info

Comment: You have to [register the NIB](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register) not the class. If you instantiate from the class the outlets are not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the code below to register XIB file in table view:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "yourNibFileName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentier")
```

Comment: it says "[<NSObject 0x600001154600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view."

Comment: Maybe it caused by a bad outlet. Check your outlet's connection in your class and also the XIB file connection inspector.

Comment: fixed the issue, tysm for helping